# How does Vec::new() know what is the requested element type?

Tags: rust

I can create vector of any type like this:

```
let mut vec: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
```

How does `new()` know what is requested vector element type when (unlike C++) it is not parametrized with type name?

On the other hand: Can I specify the type explicitely?
This doesn't seem to compile:

```
let mut vec = Vec<u32>::new();
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> On the other hand: Can I specify the type explicitely? This doesn't seem to compile:
>
> ```
> let mut vec = Vec<u32>::new();
> ```

The use of `<>` to specify generic arguments is ambiguous in an expression context where `<` could be the "less than" operator.

Thus, whenever you want to specify generic parameters explicitly in an expression context, you need to use the so-called "turbofish" operator to disambiguate:

```
let mut vec = Vec::<u32>::new();
```

This way the distinction is purely syntactic.

---

> How does `new()` know what is requested vector element type when (unlike C++) it is not parametrized with type name?

The term you are looking for is *type inference*: the ability of the compiler to infer the type from the context, without it being explicitly specified.

Different languages have different type inference algorithms:

- C++ has one-way type inference: the type of an expression can be inferred without specifying it, allowing the use of `auto` to declare a variable.
- Java has one-way type inference in the other direction for generics: `HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();`.
- Rust has two-way type inference, as it uses a variant of Hindley-Milner, making it so that you rarely have to specify the type within a function body.

For illustrative purpose, imagine the following ([Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=19cd241c61b1bbfef1311056dcccfa31)):

```
fn display(i: u64) {
    println!("{}", i);
}

fn main() {
    let mut vec = Vec::new();

    vec.push(1);
    
    display(vec[0]);
}
```

The compiler will reason in the following way:

1. `vec` has type `Vec<?0>`.
2. `Vec<?0>::push` takes an `{integer}` as argument, hence `?0` is an `{integer}`.
3. `<Vec<?0> as Index>::Output` is `?0`.
4. `display` takes a `u64` as argument, thus `?0` is `u64`.

This combination of links (threading `?0` through) allows it to gather 2 constraints:

- `?0` is an `{integer}`.
- `?0` is `u64`.

Since both constraints are satisfied by `?0` being a `u64`, then it is inferred to be a `u64`.

If however you change `display` to take a `&str`, then you'll get an error message as inference will fail:

> ```
> error[E0308]: mismatched types
>   --> src/main.rs:10:17
>    |
> 10 |         display(vec[0]);
>    |                 ^^^^^^ expected `&str`, found integer
> ```

Because satisfying `?0 = &str` and `?0 is {integer}` at the same time is impossible.

Comment: Tiny nitpick: Java does support type inference of expressions via the `var` keyword, eg: `var map = new HashMap<String, String>();`.

Comment: @Aiden4: Indeed, but since that's the same as C++ it wasn't an interesting example :)

Answer (score 11):

The Rust compiler uses a (slightly modified) [Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindley%E2%80%93Milner_type_system#An_inference_algorithm). Basically, all type information you provide in the source code is used as constraints on the unbound generic type parameters, and a constraint solver then tries to figure out all unknowns. In the case of the assignment

```
let vec: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
```

there is one unbound generic type parameter on the right-hand side – the `T` parameter of `Vec<T>`. The compiler remembers that unbound type parameter as yet to be determined. By looking at the prototype of `Vec::new()`, the compiler can see that it returns `Vec<T>`, so the expression on the right-hand side has type `Vec<T>`, with `T` still being unbound. Based on the type annotation on the left-hand side, the compiler knows that this type is supposed to be `Vec<u32>`, so it can infer that `T` must be `u32`.

This is a relatively simple case. The constraint solver is able to handle much more complex situations as well.

You can explicitly specify the type on the right-hand side using the "turbofish" operator `::<>`:

```
let vec = Vec::<u32>::new();
```

Answer (score 4):

When implementing something for a generic type the compiler is smart enough to elide the type. Even more if you specify the type directly in the variable.

Elided type to `Vec<u32>`

```rust
let mut vec = Vec::new();
vec.push(0u32);
```

variable declaration:

```rust
let mut vec: Vec<u32> = Vec::new();
```

type especification:

```rust
let mut vec = Vec::<u32>::new();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a9cd7a803b50ac7552270762441328e3)